# Is it possible to get a webhook on BIM 360 model derivative jobs you did not create?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

We have a BIM 360 app that listens when documents are given new versions and updates to the latest version. A webhook is added for (system: data, event: dm.version.added), which gets triggered, but what we are interested in is only the SVF file created by the model derivative, and this event is triggered before that has been created.

I've been poking at the webhook (system: derivative, event: extraction.finished), which seems like want I want, but that requires a workflow-id value that looks like it's created with the job. As far as I can tell there's no way to query for jobs or find the workflow IDs of running jobs; the progress report is returned in the manifest but nothing else. In this case the job is being created by BIM 360 itself, and I'm wondering if there's a system workflow ID I can subscribe to, or some other way to hear about finished jobs that I didn't create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment. 
I logged this request in our system but cannot tell if/when this might get implemented.
For your reference, the ID of the request is ALEX-39359

In the meantime, you would have to keep polling our system for an up-to-date manifest of the file in order to see how far the translation progressed or if it finished: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/

Comment: Thanks much for the info, really appreciate it! We are polling now, I was auditing things and trying to tighten some pieces up and thought this was a path, glad to have an answer.